# Managing the change of element styles. Is there a simpler way?

Tags: javascript, class

I know I am repeating myself in m JS code, its not DRY, though I am not sure how to write it in a more succinct way.

In order to change the style of elements on a click event, I follow the path of creating classes that contain the changes and then remove default classes and add new classes for the element being clicked on and then remove new classes and add default classes back again when the user clicks off the element.

Everything works 100%, though I am quite certain there is a much simpler way to do this by using some kind of loop and I am also not sure if I need all the constants I am using to hold the values of the object elements before the change - maybe there is a simpler way to access the DOM for these elements? (step 3.2 below).

I have only been learning web development for a month so I don't know what I don't know.

Can you take a look and let me know if you have a simpler approach?

I have 6 divs that share classes for a column, color, and content. They all look as follows:

```
<div class="portfolio_columns">
     <div class="colorful_box box1"></div>
     <div class='portfolio_piece piece1'>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio_columns">
     <div class="colorful_box box2"></div>
     <div class='portfolio_piece piece2'>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio_columns">
     <div class="colorful_box box3"></div>
     <div class='portfolio_piece piece3'>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio_columns">
     <div class="colorful_box box4"></div>
     <div class='portfolio_piece piece4'>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio_columns">
     <div class="colorful_box box5"></div>
     <div class='portfolio_piece piece5'>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio_columns">
     <div class="colorful_box box6"></div>
     <div class='portfolio_piece piece6'>
     </div>
</div>
```

I then create javascript so that I can listen for clicks.

I follow these steps:

Step 1. I add an ID to my HTML elements:

```
<div id="pc1" class="portfolio_columns">
     <div id="box_1" class="colorful_box box1"></div>
     <div id="piece_1" class='portfolio_piece piece1'>
     </div>
</div>

<div id="pc2" class="portfolio_columns">
     <div id="box_2" class="colorful_box box1"></div>
     <div id="piece_2" class='portfolio_piece piece1'>
     </div>
</div>

<div id="pc3" class="portfolio_columns">
     <div id="box_3" class="colorful_box box1"></div>
     <div id="piece_3" class='portfolio_piece piece1'>
     </div>
</div>

<div id="pc4" class="portfolio_columns">
     <div id="box_4" class="colorful_box box1"></div>
     <div id="piece_4" class='portfolio_piece piece1'>
     </div>
</div>

<div id="pc5" class="portfolio_columns">
     <div id="box_5" class="colorful_box box1"></div>
     <div id="piece_5" class='portfolio_piece piece1'>
     </div>
</div>

<div id="pc6" class="portfolio_columns">
     <div id="box_6" class="colorful_box box1"></div>
     <div id="piece_6" class='portfolio_piece piece1'>
     </div>
</div>
```

Step 2. I create some default styles for the classes of my divs and new classes in CSS which contain the style changes for mouse event:

```
.portfolio_columns {

}

.colorful_box {

}

.portfolio_piece {

}

.pcc {

}

.ppc {

}

.cbc {

}
```

Step 3.1. In JS I create a const that holds the element object before I make changes to it after mouse event:

```
const pcc1 = document.getElementById('pc1'),
    pcc2 = document.getElementById('pc2'),
    pcc3 = document.getElementById('pc3'),
    pcc4 = document.getElementById('pc4'),
    pcc5 = document.getElementById('pc5'),
    pcc6 = document.getElementById('pc6'),
    cbc1 = document.getElementById('box_1'),
    cbc2 = document.getElementById('box_2'),
    cbc3 = document.getElementById('box_3'),
    cbc4 = document.getElementById('box_4'),
    cbc5 = document.getElementById('box_5'),
    cbc6 = document.getElementById('box_6'),
    ppc1 = document.getElementById('piece_1'),
    ppc2 = document.getElementById('piece_2'),
    ppc3 = document.getElementById('piece_3'),
    ppc4 = document.getElementById('piece_4'),
    ppc5 = document.getElementById('piece_5'),
    ppc6 = document.getElementById('piece_6');
```

Step 3.2. I create a global variable called cnt and add an eventListener for a click on the document. Inside the eventListener I use an if statement to identify what was clicked on and if it is anything I am listening to then I add the new classes and remove classes default to my element objects accordingly. Once the user clicks off the selected element I remove the new classes and restore the default classes:

```
let cnt = 0;

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    
    if (e.target.classList.contains('box1')) {
        cnt = 1;
        pcc1.classList.remove('portfolio_columns');
        pcc1.classList.add('pcc');
        cbc1.classList.remove('colorful_box');
        cbc1.classList.add('cbc');
        ppc1.classList.remove('portfolio_piece');
        ppc1.classList.add('ppc');
    }
    else

    if (e.target.classList.contains('box2')) {
        cnt = 2;
        pcc2.classList.remove('portfolio_columns');
        pcc2.classList.add('pcc');
        cbc2.classList.remove('colorful_box');
        cbc2.classList.add('cbc');
        ppc2.classList.remove('portfolio_piece');
        ppc2.classList.add('ppc');
    }
    else

    if (e.target.classList.contains('box3')) {
        cnt = 3;
        pcc3.classList.remove('portfolio_columns');
        pcc3.classList.add('pcc');
        cbc3.classList.remove('colorful_box');
        cbc3.classList.add('cbc');
        ppc3.classList.remove('portfolio_piece');
        ppc3.classList.add('ppc');
    }
    else
    
    if (e.target.classList.contains('box4')) {
        cnt = 4;
        pcc4.classList.remove('portfolio_columns');
        pcc4.classList.add('pcc');
        cbc4.classList.remove('colorful_box');
        cbc4.classList.add('cbc');
        ppc4.classList.remove('portfolio_piece');
        ppc4.classList.add('ppc');
    }
    else

    if (e.target.classList.contains('box5')) {
        cnt = 5;
        pcc5.classList.remove('portfolio_columns');
        pcc5.classList.add('pcc');
        cbc5.classList.remove('colorful_box');
        cbc5.classList.add('cbc');
        ppc5.classList.remove('portfolio_piece');
        ppc5.classList.add('ppc');
    }
    else

    if (e.target.classList.contains('box6')) {
        cnt = 6;
        pcc6.classList.remove('portfolio_columns');
        pcc6.classList.add('pcc');
        cbc6.classList.remove('colorful_box');
        cbc6.classList.add('cbc');
        ppc6.classList.remove('portfolio_piece');
        ppc6.classList.add('ppc');
    }
    else 
    
    if (cnt > 0) {

        switch (cnt) {
            case 1: {
                pcc1.classList.remove('pcc');
                cbc1.classList.remove('cbc');
                ppc1.classList.remove('ppc');
                pcc1.classList.add('portfolio_columns');
                cbc1.classList.add('colorful_box');
                ppc1.classList.add('portfolio_piece');
            }
            break;
            case 2: {
                pcc2.classList.remove('pcc');
                cbc2.classList.remove('cbc');
                ppc2.classList.remove('ppc');
                pcc2.classList.add('portfolio_columns');
                cbc2.classList.add('colorful_box');
                ppc2.classList.add('portfolio_piece');
            }
            break;
            case 3: {
                pcc3.classList.remove('pcc');
                cbc3.classList.remove('cbc');
                ppc3.classList.remove('ppc');
                pcc3.classList.add('portfolio_columns');
                cbc3.classList.add('colorful_box');
                ppc3.classList.add('portfolio_piece');
            }
            break;
            case 4: {
                pcc4.classList.remove('pcc');
                cbc4.classList.remove('cbc');
                ppc4.classList.remove('ppc');
                pcc4.classList.add('portfolio_columns');
                cbc4.classList.add('colorful_box');
                ppc4.classList.add('portfolio_piece');
            }
            break;
            case 5: {
                pcc5.classList.remove('pcc');
                cbc5.classList.remove('cbc');
                ppc5.classList.remove('ppc');
                pcc5.classList.add('portfolio_columns');
                cbc5.classList.add('colorful_box');
                ppc5.classList.add('portfolio_piece');
            }
            case 6: {
                pcc6.classList.remove('pcc');
                cbc6.classList.remove('cbc');
                ppc6.classList.remove('ppc');
                pcc6.classList.add('portfolio_columns');
                cbc6.classList.add('colorful_box');
                ppc6.classList.add('portfolio_piece');
            }
        }
    }
    
        
    });
```

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you could add complete HTML here even though it has exactly the same syntax.

Comment: Change only the ascendant selector, and use [descendant combinators](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) in your CSS.

Comment: @decpk I have added remaining html

Comment: @SebastianSimon the css is fine and uses descendant combinators. I am asking about the javascript - specifically the last step and how to refactor that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve. However I think I can give you some general pointers to improve your code.

If you have duplicate code, put the code in a function and use function arguments if necessary.

You do not want to duplicate the structure of your HTML in your JavaScript code. If you add a new `portfolio_columns` to your HTML, you have to update your JavaScript also. That's error prone and not very convenient.

A way to achieve this is to not work with IDs and `getElementById()` but to work with classes and `querySelectorAll()`. This function is available on `document` but also on all `Element`s.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio_columns').forEach( ... );
```

If you do need some additional data for a specific element, use `data-*` attributes to keep everything in the HTML:

```html
<div class="portfolio_columns" data-index="1">
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio_columns').forEach(el => {
  const index = el.dataset.index; // '1'
  ...
});
```

Usually you do not need to remove default classes. Default classes should apply default styling. You then add other classes to override the default styling, for example to highlight an item. You can easily toggle a class using `Element.classList.toggle()`.

You should register the `click` event listener on the relevant elements, not on the document itself. The event handler is then only run for clicks on the elements, not for clicks on other parts of the document.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.box').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.classList.toggle('active-box');
  });
});
```

Do not use `function` expressions for event handlers and callbacks, use arrow functions.

Comment: Thank you SO much for your time and help. It's exactly what I needed and was looking for. The data-* attribute is going to add incredible value and all your other points are well noted. Thank you!